# MySQL Getting Records over the Last Working Week

Tags: mysql, week-number

I'm using

```
 WHERE WEEK(curdate,3)-WEEK(date)=1
```

to get all lines of a table that are recorded on the last working week (Monday to Sunday). Works well the whole year, but in January that will return 0 for some time, so I have to take

```
 WHERE WEEK(curdate,3)+53-WEEK(date)
```

in that case. I can't use `OR` because it would take both current year info and last year info when both exist. I already tried `COALESCE` and `IFNULL` methods:

```
 WHERE COALESCE(
     (WEEK(curdate(),3)-WEEK(date,3) = 1),
     (WEEK(curdate(),3)+53-WEEK(date,3) = 1
 )
```

It works well for the whole year but doesn't manage the case when `IFNULL` is true.
Please give me advice on effective handling of this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date of the Monday of the current week using:

```
select SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()));
```

and then use the date of the Monday of this week and the Monday of the previous week in your predicate:

```
WHERE date >= SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate())) - interval 1 week
AND date < SUBDATE(curdate(), WEEKDAY(curdate()))
```