# how to get data weekly. Only till Monday to Next Sunday

Tags: php, mysql, date, weekend

I have coded a program in which i can get data of last 7 days. But i want that my data should be visible of Last week and Week starts from Monday and Ends at Sunday. Then on Monday next Week starts.
So i want if today is Wednesday and If i click on week report. Then it should get data till last Monday only . Like (Wednesday, Tuesday, Monday) But My System Counts complete 7 Days.
Here are my Codes.

```
date_default_timezone_set("EST");
$wdate = date('Y-m-d');
$wdate_to = $wdate;
$wdate_to = strtotime("-7 days", strtotime($wdate_to)); //-7 days for last week. -30 for last week
$wdate_to = date("Y-m-d", $wdate_to);


$wget_req = "SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `assign_date` between '$wdate_to' AND '$wdate' AND `assigned`=1";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $wget_req);

while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $driver_id = $res['assigned_driver_id'];
    $req_id = $res['req_id'];
    $req_title = $res['request_title'];
    $req_price = $res['price'];
    $req_time = $res['request_time'];
    $req_date = $res['assign_date'];
    $req_desc = $res['req_desc'];
    $assigned = $res['assigned'];
    $status = $res['req_status'];
    $driver = $res['driver_name'];
$get_record = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `Memberid`='$driver_id' AND `u_level`=3";
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_record);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

    $status = $row['u_status'];
}
?>

                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td><b><?php echo $driver ;?></b></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $driver_id ;?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $req_date ;?></td>
                                            <td><b><?php echo $wdate_to;?></b> &#8596; <b><?php echo $wdate ;?></b></td>
                                            <td class="center"><?php if($status == 1){echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Driver is not working. Deactivated</a>';}else if($status == 0){echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Driver is Active. Working</a>';}?></td>
                                            <td class="center"> <a href="weekly_report.php?driver_id=<?php echo $driver_id ;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Report</a>
 </td>
                                        </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

I hope to get help soon

Comment: What is the issue with the current code? Maybe this is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154655/mysql-getting-records-over-the-last-working-week

Comment: it shows data of Last 7 Days.. I want the data till last monday i mean weak starts from Monday ends at Sunday. So it should get data till last Monday

Comment: Try SQL answer linked above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it may help you

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("EST");
$wdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('monday this week'));
$wdate_to = $wdate;
$wdate_to = strtotime("-7 days", strtotime($wdate_to)); //-7 days for last week. -30 for last week
$wdate_to = date("Y-m-d", $wdate_to);


$wget_req = "SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `assign_date` between '$wdate_to' AND '$wdate' AND `assigned`=1";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $wget_req);

while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $driver_id = $res['assigned_driver_id'];
    $req_id = $res['req_id'];
    $req_title = $res['request_title'];
    $req_price = $res['price'];
    $req_time = $res['request_time'];
    $req_date = $res['assign_date'];
    $req_desc = $res['req_desc'];
    $assigned = $res['assigned'];
    $status = $res['req_status'];
    $driver = $res['driver_name'];
$get_record = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `Memberid`='$driver_id' AND `u_level`=3";
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_record);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

    $status = $row['u_status'];
}
?>

                                        <tr class="gradeA">
                                            <td><b><?php echo $driver ;?></b></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $driver_id ;?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $req_date ;?></td>
                                            <td><b><?php echo $wdate_to;?></b> &#8596; <b><?php echo $wdate ;?></b></td>
                                            <td class="center"><?php if($status == 1){echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Driver is not working. Deactivated</a>';}else if($status == 0){echo '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Driver is Active. Working</a>';}?></td>
                                            <td class="center"> <a href="weekly_report.php?driver_id=<?php echo $driver_id ;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">View Report</a>
 </td>
                                        </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This Worked.. Thank you Do Much @Dhinjy

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
//Returns values 0-6, 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday))
$currentDay = date('w') - 1;

//Your week start on Monday, so if today is Sunday, you need to adjust the value
if($currentDay < 0) {
    $currentDay = 6;
}
$weekStartTimestamp = time() - $currentDay * 24 * 60 * 60;
$wdate_to = date("Y-m-d", $weekStartTimestamp);
```

Comment: i am sorry but why $currentDay=6; It mean we are commanding system that today is 6th day of week??

Comment: Your week starts with Monday ($currentDay = 0) and the last day is Sunday ($currentDay = 6). So if today is Sunday, you will have to substract 6 days from the current timestamp to get the timestamp of Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Get monday date from given date. Here my given date is 15th July 2015.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("previous monday", strtotime("2015-07-15")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$currentDay = date('w');
$curDate = date('d-m-Y');
//$curDate = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("-1 week")); // uncomment this line if u want to get data of last week
$mon = $curDate;
if($currentDay > 1){
    $day = $currentDay-1;
    $mon = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($curDate. ' - '.$day.' days'));
}

$sat = $curDate;
if($currentDay !=7){
    $day = (6 -$currentDay);
    $sat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($curDate. ' + '.$day.' days'));
}
echo $mon;
echo '<br>';
echo $sat;
```